# Summarizing a grouped dataframe while maintaining all columns that are factor vectors

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe containing performance data for several individuals over the course of a time frame. Instead of having each individual performance by each person, I want a dataframe containing totals/averages of each individual person. Here is a sample dataframe:

```
name<-c("dwayne", "alf", "christine", "katerina", "dwayne", "christine")
team<- c("halifax", "hamilton", "calgary", "winnipeg", "halifax", "calgary")
pos<- c("left", "middle", "middle", "right", "left", "middle")
amt1<- c(4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 7)
amt2 <- c(12, 14, 13, 18, 17, 18)
perc1<- c(.55, .24, .67, .45, .34, .54)
perc2<- c(.12, .14, .16, .04, .02, .13)

df<-data_frame(team, pos, name, amt1, amt2, perc1, perc2)
```

So far, I have figured out how to use group_by and summarize_if to accomplish this with the numeric columns, like so:

```
tot<-df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(amt1:amt2), sum)

av <- df %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(perc1:perc2), mean)

bnd<-cbind(tot, av)

bnd <- bnd[, !duplicated(colnames(bnd))]
```

However, my problem is this: this method returns a dataframe that does not contain the columns "pos" or "team. These are key pieces of information in analyzing this data, but are not numeric so are dropped when using the summarize function. How can I return the dataframe "bnd", while still having those factor vectors present?

Comment: May be you need to use `mutate_at` and then get the `distinct` rows

Comment: Not quite sure I follow, real rookie here. Appreciate any further explanation, but also happy to try and figure it.

Comment: If each `name` is associated with a single `team` and a `single` position, then group by these additional columns (i.e., `group_by(name, pos, team)`) and they will be present in all output. If a player can have more than one team (say, because they changed teams during the relevant time-frame) or plays more than one position, then you'd have to make some decisions about how you want to summarize the data.

Comment: @eipi10 yeah, it is sports data, so possible that players can move teams or play multiple positions. This makes it much more difficult I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the combination of team, pos and name is unique you can include those variables into your grouping

```
tot <- df %>%
  group_by(team, pos, name) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(amt1:amt2), sum) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 x 5
  team     pos    name       amt1  amt2
  <chr>    <chr>  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 calgary  middle christine    12    31
2 halifax  left   dwayne        9    29
3 hamilton middle alf           2    14
4 winnipeg right  katerina      8    18
```

Comment: Unfortunately the combination is not unique. It is sports data, so entirely possible that players transfer teams or play multiple positions.

Comment: Ok, but if a single player can have multiple positions, e.g. middle and left. Which position would you like to assign to your summarised scores for this specific player?

Comment: I suppose whichever position is assigned to them most frequently

I could also work with the dataframe containing multiple rows for a single player, one for each position they have appeared in.

Comment: If multiple rows for a single player is fine then my proposed solution works. I don't know what you want to do in the end but I would go this way over the idea to assign the most frequent position. What is true for position is also true for team. Thus you will have a row for each player-position-team combination

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to summarize player results separately for each team or position, then another option to deal with multiple teams/positions is to keep them all. For each `name`, combine the unique values of `team` into a single string, and likewise for `pos`. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Added a couple of additional rows for illustration
df = data.frame(name=c("dwayne", "alf", "christine", "katerina", "dwayne", "christine", "christine", "dwayne"),
                team= c("halifax", "hamilton", "calgary", "winnipeg", "halifax", "calgary", "halifax","halifax"),
                pos= c("left", "middle", "middle", "right", "left", "middle", "middle","middle"),
                amt1= c(4, 2, 5, 8, 5, 7,5,5),
                amt2 = c(12, 14, 13, 18, 17, 18,17,13),
                perc1= c(.55, .24, .67, .45, .34, .54,.56,.51),
                perc2= c(.12, .14, .16, .04, .02, .13, .11, .09))

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(team = paste(unique(team), collapse="-"),
         pos = paste(unique(pos), collapse="-")) %>% 
  group_by(name, team, pos) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(amt1:amt2), sum)
```

> ```
>   name      team            pos          amt1  amt2
> 1 alf       hamilton        middle          2    14
> 2 christine calgary-halifax middle         17    48
> 3 dwayne    halifax         left-middle    14    42
> 4 katerina  winnipeg        right           8    18
> ```